# Can repartition in spark affect stage 0?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have set of data partitioned by date, and intend to read them and group by user_id.

```
inputdata
  .groupBy(col("user_id"))
  .count
```

In my job Stage 0, averaged over two runs, takes around 30 minutes.

If I change the code to

```
inputdata
  .repartition(col("user_id"), 30)
  .groupBy(col("user_id"))
  .count
```

The runtime for Stage 0 reduces to around 15 minutes, again averaged over two runs.

This seems entirely illogical to me. I would expect that, if anything, Stage 0's runtime should increase. Does anyone have any insight?

Background info:

- It's 30 partitions at the beginning (30 days worth of data).
- Around 6000000000 rows.
- Around 14000000 user ids.
- Running on data stored in a Hadoop cluster in parquet format.

Comment: It's 30 partitions at the beginning (30 days worth of data).
Around 6000000000 rows.
Around 14000000 user ids
Running on data stored in a hadoop cluster in parquet format.

Comment: And what is the SQL type of `user_id`?